# Word for dislike of doing things unnecessarily

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for people who can't stand doing things unnecessarily resulting in waste? (Of time, energy, money etc)

E.g. I consider myself to be a ______. I can't stand unnecessary waste.

Like how a pacifist is someone who doesn't have an affinity towards violence.

Comment: Answers given include frugal, unwasteful, thrifty, economical, efficient // optimiser, economiser.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend coining a new word here.

Since you are all about efficiency I humbly offer:

> **Efficionado**
>
> Noun : efficionado; plural noun: efficionados
>
> A person who is very focused on efficiency in all endeavors, and appreciates it
>   in other persons and procesess.

Answer (score 0):

There is the word **thrifty** about which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/thrifty) says

> **thrifty**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1** Using money and other resources carefully and not wastefully.

So you could say

> I consider myself to be a **thrifty** person.

I would like to put

> I consider myself to be a **thrift**.

but I don't remember seeing it used in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Different words capture different senses of this.

*conservative* - be careful of political confusion. can be adjoined to different words to clarify the kind of conservative you are, eg. "environmental conservative" monitors their waste, plants trees, learns about local ecosystems and industries.

*pedant* - as in, pedantic. Will fuss over details to finish a task "the right way" or keep things going. Can't stand a half-done job. The meaning could actually work against your favour, in implying you'll waste time to get minor tasks done a certain way, but one can be a pedant about schedules as well and rely on everything being ordered to be efficient.

The answer above of "thrifty" I didn't like so much for the laidback sense, but it does actually answer the question you raised(money).

Answer (score 0):

**Economical** is more general choice. One can be economical in one's means, or in one's motion, or in one's use of words. While “thrifty” is a good alternative, in common usage it often implies careful use only of money.

> **economical** | ˌekəˈnämik(ə)l, ˌēkəˈnämik(ə)l |
>   adjective
>   
> giving good value or service in relation to the amount of money, time, or effort spent: *a small, economical car*.
>   
> • (of a person or lifestyle) careful not to waste money or resources.
>   
> • using no more of something than is necessary: this chassis is economical in metal and therefore light in weight.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing to what you describe is frugality.  So you'd use 'a frugal person'
Wikipedia gives:
'Frugality is the quality of being frugal, sparing, thrifty, prudent or economical in the consumption of consumable resources such as food, time or money, and avoiding waste, lavishness or extravagance.'

Answer (score -3):

> **wastefully**

why not putting the word inside the sentence itself :

> I consider myself to be a **wastefully**. I can't stand unnecessary
>   waste.

since the waste is focusing on variety things, just the *"waste"* itself is fine.

Comment: Wastefully? Should we use 'to be' after consider?

Comment: This means the exact opposite of what the user wanted.

Comment: I have voted this down as the answer is completely wrong and shows a lack of understanding of English: "wastefully" is an adverb and cannot be used as a noun or adjective.

Comment: Amzar, you might like to take the [Tour] of our site; amongst other things it explains that EL&U is for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". We expect an answer to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. For those who are still developing their English skills, our sister site [ell.se] is a useful resource. :-)